# Interpreting the Teletype free monad in the RWS monad

Tags: haskell, free-monad

I'm currently learning about free monads and I was toying with probably the simplest and most common example out there – `Teletype`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}

import Control.Monad.Free

data TeletypeF a = Put String a
                 | Get (String -> a)
    deriving Functor

type Teletype = Free TeletypeF
```

Many tutorials interpret `Teletype` programs in the `IO` monad. For example:

```
-- Utilities
get   = liftF $ Get id
put s = liftF $ Put s ()

-- Sample programs
echo :: Teletype ()
echo = do word <- get
          if word == "\04"  -- Ctrl-D
          then return ()
          else put word >> echo

hello :: Teletype ()
hello = do put "What is your name?"
           name <- get
           put "What is your age?"
           age <- get
           put ("Hello, " ++ name ++ "!")
           put ("You are " ++ age ++ " years old!")

-- Interpret to IO
interpIO :: Teletype a -> IO a
interpIO = foldFree lift
    where
        lift (Put s a) = putStrLn s >> return a
        lift (Get f)   = getLine >>= return . f
```

I was trying to interpret it in a different monad, namely the [RWS](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-RWS-Lazy.html) monad.
This idea was motivated by the last exercise from [this assignment](http://www.cs.uu.nl/docs/vakken/afp/assignment3.html).
I'm using the `RWS` datatype to fetch input from the `Reader` part and accumulate output in the `State` part.
But, unfortunately, I'm not able to get it working. Here is my attempt so far:

```
import Control.Monad.Trans.RWS.Lazy hiding (get, put)

type TeletypeRWS = RWS [String] () [String]

-- Interpret to TeletypeRWS
interpRWS :: Teletype a -> TeletypeRWS a
interpRWS = foldFree lift
    where
        lift (Put s a) = state (\t -> ((), t ++ [s])) >> return a
        lift (Get f)   = reader head >>= local tail . return . f  -- This is wrong

mockConsole :: Teletype a -> [String] -> (a, [String])
mockConsole p inp = (a, s)
    where
        (a, s, _) = runRWS (interpRWS p) inp []
```

When running the `TeletypeRWS` "programs", the first value in the environment is not removed:

```
*Main> mockConsole hello ["john", "18"]
((),["What is your name?","What is your age?","Hello, john!","You are john years old!"])
```

I am a bit uneasy about updating the `Reader`, but I don't know how else I can access the next value in the list. The type of `TeletypeRWS` was chosen based on the exercise mentioned above – so I assume it should be possible to implement `interpRWS`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can't use `foldFree`: it needs to be parametric in the continuation, so we can't apply `local` there. In contrast, `iterM` explicitly gives us the actual continuation without generalization, so this will work.

```
interpRWS = iterM lift where
  lift (Put s a) = modify (\t -> t ++ [s]) >> a
  lift (Get f)   = reader head >>= local tail . f
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! The suggested changes do indeed work as expected, but I'm having some trouble understanding why they do. The two functions, `iterM` and `foldFree`, seem very related and I'm not sure I grasp the differences – when should I prefer one over the other? For example, I could also implement `interpIO` in terms of `iterM`. Why does the current implementation of `interpIO`, which is based on `foldFree`, work?

Comment: `local` modifies the environment in which to run a computation, that is given to it as an argument. With `foldFree` you do not have access to the computation you want to apply `local` to. In `foldFree :: ... => (forall x. f x -> m x) -> Free f a -> m a`, that computation is hidden in the universally quantified `x`. In `iterM :: ... => (f (m a) -> m a) -> Free f a -> m a` that computation is the `m a` inside `f`, so that gives you the opportunity to use `local`.

Comment: There is no general rule to decide which one to use. Whatever you can do with `foldFree`, you can do with `iterM`, and at the lowest level you can just pattern match on the `Free` value. However the higher level of abstraction `foldFree` often makes programs easier to understand once you are familiar with free monads.